# PHP command execution not working the same

Tags: php, apache, command

So i am trying to run a command in windows from php. I have a php file that runs a program PDFtoPrinter

The php looks like

```
$output = shell_exec(‘C:\PDFtoPrinter\PDFtoPRINTER.exe C:\Wamp\www\upload\’.$file;
echo $output
```

so if i run

```
C:\PDFtoPrinter\PDFtoPRINTER.exe C:\Wamp\www\upload\file.pdf
```

in command prompt it works great and prints two sided

when it runs through the php file it prints two pages one sided each.
Could this be a property issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to have Apache to run as the same user I set the default printer settings in